# Could you explain how instant messengers work over UDP in layman terms?

Tags: router, udp

It is clear how TCP works: it is stateful, and routers can maintain state on endpoints' behalf. But it is not clear how it works for UDP. I imagine a not-so-hypothetical scenario:

Several clients on a LAN behind a router run instant messenger X that uses a standard random port, for example 50000. They send their packets to a server in the cloud. Their router knows: client #1 sent a UDP packet from IP 1.2.3.4 port 5000; client #2 sent a UDP packet from IP 1.2.3.5 port 50000; so on. Now the server has to respond.

What does the server in the cloud know about it? It seems to me that it knows that a router at 2.3.4.5 sent it 2x packets from port 50000. What can tell to which IM client its response belongs and how? And how is this problem solved in real life?

Comment: Are you asking how router NAT works with stateless protocols, or are you asking how the endpoints (servers & clients) work?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, routers do not *need* to maintain state on endpoints' behalf. All they need to do is forward IP packets, regardless of their contents. A router only needs to keep state per-connection when it has a) a stateful firewall meant to allow connections in one direction, and/or b) a stateful NAT such as the typical "many-to-one" masquerading found in home routers. But in both cases, routing remains fully stateless – it is the *firewall* coexisting in the same router that does keep state.

But both the firewall and the endpoints can still keep state even if they don't have explicit signals (like from TCP SYN or FIN packets) – instead the firewall automatically creates state entries from *every* UDP packet that goes through it, and destroys them after a timeout. (Similarly, UDP-based servers will use timeouts to automatically clean up state.)

1. The request from a client to a server uses a new random source port. The firewall doesn't have it in the state table, so it adds a new state entry (typically with a 30s timeout), and any NAT mappings are recorded in that state entry as usual.
2. The reply from the DNS server arrives to a destination port that's in the state table, so the firewall knows which internal host to NAT the reply to. (Usually the firewall also extends the state timeout when it sees bidirectional communication, e.g. to 120s.)
3. The client and server continue exchanging UDP packets between the same ports, e.g. the entire conversation is between client:22162 ⇄ server:53, so the packets still match the firewall state established by the 1st packet, and every such packet causes the firewall to renew the state expiry timeout to the full 120s.
4. If there are no packets between client & server for more than 120s, the firewall's state expires. Because of this, software that implement long-lived communications over UDP (e.g. games, IM software, VPN tunnels) will often send "keep-alive" packets when idle.

---

You can always build stateful protocols *on top* of a stateless transport – exactly like TCP itself is carried by a stateless IP. The only difference is that the state isn't managed by the OS (like with TCP) but by the servers and clients themselves.

(A good example is SCTP, which is a transport protocol like TCP and normally handled by OS sockets just like TCP, but is also often implemented by programs themselves using libsctp and carried over UDP.)